# I have two programs with same contents but their name differ by a prefix * (example : out8.c and *out.c). The one with *prefix doesnt compile

Tags: c

[screenshot of prefix error in c language  ]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMNSs.png]

Comment: because, `*` is considered as a wild card , you are basically telling the compiler to compile any file that ends with `out.c`. refer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character .

Comment: Compile and run the one that works, delete the other, (very carefully!).

Comment: Try `gcc "*out.c"`.

Answer (score 1):

You have two files: `out.c` and `*out.c`. The latter has the shell wildcard character `*`.

So, when you compile with `gcc *out.c`, the shell expands the wildcard and it is as if you had typed: `gcc \*out.c out.c`.

Notice that the error messages mention both `out.c` and `*out.c`

For your sanity, rename `*out.c` into something else that does not have the wildcard (e.g. `out2.c`)

Answer (score 1):

By doing `gcc *out.c`, you're trying to compile all files that match `*out.c`, which are both of your files, thus the "multiple definition of addmult" and "multiple definition of main" errors. This happens because the `*` is treated as a wildcard.

For example, `gcc *.c` would compile all .c files present.
Try to change the `*out.` to something that doesn't start with a wildcard and you'll be fine.